# I need an alternative to the first fit decreasing bin packing algorithm that always finds an optimal solution

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have implemented the First-Fit-Decreasing bin packing algorithm to split a list of numbers into two 'bins' of equal size. The algorithm almost always finds the optimal packing arrangement but occasionally it doesn't.

For example:

The set of numbers 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2 can obviously be split into this arrangement:
1) 4, 3, 2
2) 4, 3, 2

The first fit decreasing algorithm does not find a solution.

It is not acceptable in this circumstance to NOT find the correct solution if one exists.

The original puzzle is to split a sequence of numbers into two sets that have an equal sum.

Is this just a simple bin packing problem or have I used the wrong algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bin packing is NP complete.

> It is not acceptable in this circumstance to NOT find the correct solution if one exists.

Try the *Branch and Bound* algorithm, but like all the exact algorithms, it doesn't scale to medium or big problems.

*First-Fit-Decreasing* is a good starting deterministic algorithm, but you can do much better by chaining it with *meta-heuristics* such as *Simulated Annealing*, *Tabu Search* or *Genetic Algorithms*. There are a couple of open source libs out there which can do that for you, such as [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (java).